# Android simple drag & drop library

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-view

Is there a library for moving views by dragging & dropping on Android? I don't want any fancy animations or anything, just users can drag the `ImageButton`s to anywhere in the screen and they will stay where they are dropped.

I googled it and searched for it but I couldn't find anything ready to use, will I be required to implement it using `onTouch` and stuff?

By the way, my API level is 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Drag and Drop tutorial in the [API Guides.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm developing in API 8. Does Android Support library has this functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't believe so. Some people have successfully used the following tutorial to implement drag and drop in the lower API levels: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/

Comment: The tutorial you supplied really helped me implementing it, thank you very much.